# Can lxml.xpath convert <td/> to ""

Tags: python, lxml

I'm using lxml to parse html string such as :

```
<tr>
 <td>111</td>   
 <td>222</td>                                   
 <td>20201208</td>                                 
 <td></td>                                  
 <td>26</td>                                   
 <td>1431</td>                                 
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

The result of html.xpath is

```
["111","222","20201208","26","1431"]
```

My question is can I get a result like

```
 ["111","222","20201208","","26","1431",""]
```

Is there any option in lxml that can do this

I use following code to fetch element:

```
tds=tr.xpath(".//td/text()")
```

Comment: add your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how you do it with ElementTree or with lxml (its the same code - just different import)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

xml = '''<tr>
 <td>111</td>   
 <td>222</td>                                   
 <td>20201208</td>                                 
 <td></td>                                  
 <td>26</td>                                   
 <td>1431</td>                                 
 <td></td>
</tr>'''

root1 = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = [td.text if td.text else '' for td in root1.findall('.//td')]
print(data)

root2 = etree.fromstring(xml)
data = [td.text if td.text else '' for td in root2.findall('.//td')]
print(data)
```

output

```
['111', '222', '20201208', '', '26', '1431', '']

['111', '222', '20201208', '', '26', '1431', '']
```

Comment: OP is using lxml, though the answer would be pretty similar.

Comment: @JackFleeting lxml was added.